# css not working correctly in mozila firefox

Tags: css

When I develop a website then css is not working in mozila firefox and it show 0 rule applied but css is applied in chrome and IE but not shown in mozila

[image]

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO.  Please take a tour of the help center and see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to validate your css here:

https://validator.w3.org/

This enables you to see if there are any problems with the css you wrote. Also if this does not help you, please include your css in the question. That will make it easier to help you :D